# Favicon.ico not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

This is my code for favicon.ico:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/...../favicon.ico', :rel => 'shortcut icon' %>
```

It works locally, but when I upload it to server - the favicon is not displayed.
I can access the image, and the image is stored on amazon server - s3 service
Help, please?

Comment: Can you view the source and post it above? also, are there any errors showing up in your logs when it tries to grab the asset?

Comment: Kyle C i'm beginner with ruby. Can you tell me where can I look for these info? Then I'll post them

Comment: right click on your web page and click view source and find the link tag to your favicon. Then depending on your deployment platform you will have to view your logs ( if your on heroku, run "heroku logs" from your terminal)

Comment: Can't find anything in log. This is what I get in Source code. It seems strange to me: <link type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/..../favicon.ico">

Comment: that is correct... I am guessing it is a cache issue. Try visiting your site from another browser and also go into your current browser tools and delete the cache

Comment: Kyle C: I tried to visit my site from another browser and another computer, but favicon is not displayed. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Where are you hosting your app? Also, try taking of the ssl on the request, just make it 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/

Answer (score 2):

Clear your browser's cache. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> should work for most of the browsers.